# Getting records from a MYSQL database between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which retrieves the records between two dates, this works fine when the dates are in the past using the following code.

```
SELECT * FROM joborders WHERE closing_date <= ( NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ) AND closing_date >= ( NOW() - INTERVAL 11520 MINUTE )
```

However when I want to see if there are any records in the future, by changing the - sign to plus signs like below.

```
SELECT * FROM joborders WHERE closing_date <= ( NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ) AND closing_date >= ( NOW() + INTERVAL 11520 MINUTE )
```

I don't get any results or any errors. even though there are records within the time range. I have tried re-writing this, and changing the plus signs to greater than etc, but nothing i do makes a difference or just gives error messages.

Comment: You're not looking for dates in the future though, you're looking for dates that are older than 1 minute from but also newer than 11,520 minutes from now.... closing_date <= ( NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ) AND closing_date >= ( NOW() + INTERVAL 11520 MINUTE )

Comment: I.e. your query based on right now would actually say closing_date <= "2014-09-12 16:28:00" AND closing_date >= "2014-09-20 16:28:00" - of course there are zero results. just need to verify you set the intervals/range correctly.

Comment: Thanks skrilled, im trying to look for seven days in the future, because people post jobs and add a closing date and so the database table will have records that are 7 days from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula for getting datetime or timestamp values in a range is this ...

```
 WHERE column >= starting_time
   AND column <  immediately_after_ending_time
```

Your second query has the starting and ending times reversed so you won't get any rows that match. You need this instead.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM joborders
 WHERE closing_date >= ( NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE )
   AND closing_date <  ( NOW() + INTERVAL 8 DAY )   /* 11520 minutes */
```

Comment: Thanks, now i see the problem,I completley over looked that.